# String keeps saying null on print even though it has data in it

Tags: java, arrays, string, null

I am generating a string in this code and then applying a substring to it.

```
String input = "AnyString"

for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
//i tracks which line we are on when printing the triangle
{
    int tracker = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++)
    //j tracks which "column of the line" we are currently on
    {
        if(i + 1 == input.length()
        //If we are on the the last line of the triangle
        || Math.abs(j - line.length()/2) == i)
        //or if the column we are on is i letters away from the center
        {
            outputs[i] += line.charAt(j);
            out.println("Outputs has been updated with:\n"+line.charAt(i));
            out.println("\nAnd it is now:\n"+outputs[i]);
            tracker = j;
            //tracker will keep track of what the position of the last letter was
        }else{
            out.println("Outputs has been updated with: a space");
            out.println("\nAnd it is now: "+outputs[i]);
            outputs[i] += " ";
        }
    }
    //Where the substring is applied
}
```

When it runs for the first loop, the output is:

**Outputs has been updated with: a space**

**And it is now: null**

Any ideas why the string says that it is null even though I've added in the space before printing? I just noticed, on the output, there is a space before it says null. For now, I will make a statement to remove the word null from the string, but if anyone can suggest a less obtuse solution, I'd appreciate it.

Thank you all for your time and attention!

Comment: what is input and line ?

Comment: Probably because output[] was initialized too large and now you are trying to retrieve element data that was never applied to that specific index. Use a Debugger to see what is going on.

Comment: Your code adds a space **after** printing, not **before** as the message says. And at the time, it prints null because outputs[i] has not been assigned a value yet.

Comment: In a situation like this ... *"Use a Debugger to see what is going on."* - .... or just read the code carefully, examining it from the perspective of what the code will actually do rather than what you want it to do.

Comment: The string `"And it is now: "` ends with a space. Without a space, it would be `"And it is now:"`. So that space between `":"` and `"null"` comes from the `"And it is: "` part, not the `outputs[i]` part.

Comment: @meriton Sorry, I thought you hadn't responded and I deleted it before I saw that comment. I realized later on that I was wrong about that when I was mulling it over in my editor. Thank you for your time sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printed output is coming from the `else` branch.

There is no code path above the `else` in which `outputs[i]` is set, so its value is `null`.

You do not get a `NullPointerException` in the print statement or at `outputs[i] += " ";` because of a quirk in the way both those statements handle null values.

`println` and concatenation always do `String.valueOf()` on their arguments. A null String value in both cases becomes the string `"null"`.

Comment: @meriton You are correct, of course.  I was being careless :-( I'll fix it. (Thx)

Comment: I think I understand, essentially: Because I haven't given it a value, it defaults to null? I thought that adding a value to it, such as " " would make it remove null because it would update to realize it is not null anymore. Thank you!